# Partition in postgresql query giving ambiguous results

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

There are few restaurants(say A) in our db which opens in multiple slots(say 2) slots:

- slot 1: 11:00 am to 1:30 pm
- slot 2: 07:00 pm to 09:00 pm.

I want to select the correct slot when restaurant will open based on current time. For example if current time is 06:15 PM then query should return slot 2, if current time is 09:00 AM then slot 1 should get returned and if it is 10:00 PM then slot 1 should return. Hence the next appropriate slot should come.

timings of restaurants are stored in `dish_timings_delivery` table with columns as shown in figure:
[image: screenshot to show data]
My query:

```
SELECT * from (
 SELECT *,row_number() over (partition by id ) as x from (
 SELECT id,day,start_time,end_time,slot from dish_timings_delivery where id in
 (101999001247,101999001225,10199900100,101999001223) order by case 
 when current_time + interval '5 hours 30 minutes' <= end_time then 1
 else 2
 end
 ) as foo ) as pp where x < 2
```

The problem is that , for one `dish_id`(say `101999001247`) query returns correct result, but for multiple `dish_ids`(say `101999001247, 101999001225, 10199900100, 101999001223`) as in above query the results are incorrect. For some restaurants slot is coming wrong.

By wrong i mean this:

**NOTE**:The value of current_time  - interval '1 hours 30 minutes' is 12:26:34 at time of posting.

Result for multiple dish_ids:
[image: multiple_dish_ids]

It should give slot 1 but giving slot 2 for some dish ids

Comment: For the failing case, what is the data in the table, what result are you getting, and what result do you expect?

Comment: @jmarkmurphy plz check the new update.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "wrong"?  You have this statement:

```
row_number() over (partition by id ) as x
```

There is no `order by`, so the returned row is arbitrary.  I suspect you want this:

```
SELECT pp.*
FROM (SELECT id, day, start_time, end_time, slot,
             row_number() over (partition by id
                                order by (case when current_time + interval '5 hours 30 minutes' <= end_time then 1
                                               else 2
                                          end) as x 
      FROM dish_timings_delivery 
      WHERE id in (101999001247, 101999001225, 10199900100, 101999001223) 
     ) pp
WHERE x < 2;
```

Key point:  The `ORDER BY` is part of the `OVER` syntax.  It is different from the `ORDER BY` clause used for a query.

In addition, you don't need two levels of subqueries.

Comment: I tried your query but it still gives wrong results as before. I have posted screenshots in the question for reference.